# Eclipse Helios and SVN?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, eclipse-3.6

I installed eclipse helios (for Java developers) and installed svn via help, install new software.

When checking out a new Java project (for example by selecting new Project.. and then choosing  checkout from SVN the sources always land next to the src folder and not in it (in some cases it does not even create an src folder). With the result that I cannot run the project. When dragging the sources manually in the src folder, eclipse then interprets this as an svn move command which I don't want.

Any ideas how to get the sources after checkout in the src directory of a new java project?

**Update**

For example after checking out some subproject of apache's cocoon it does not put them into the src directory.

[image: eclipse svn co]

Comment: I remember having used svn from eclipse some time ago and it worked find.. but now I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong..

Comment: Which SVN plugin are you using? Subclipse or Subversive?

Comment: The official one.. subversive

Comment: Can you give us example Subversion URL you are checking out and the name of the directory being created? Because you mentioned "in some cases", so it makes me wonders why would it have random behaviours.

Comment: No the svn repo is private and it depends on the path taken, eg new project -> from svn or click checkout in the svn explorer. Anyways if you just checkout any project it will not land in the src directory here I think.

Comment: "You've earned the "Notable Question" badge for Eclipse Helios and SVN??" lol Obviously quite a lot of people are pissed by the SVN integration into Eclipse..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured this out, when creating a new project you can choose whether sources should be put in an src directory or not (src directory is default) if you choose not to it works.